# Find previous div before specific element of class

Tags: jquery, selector

Ok so i have this

```
<div id="stadiumSeats1" class="fans eleven"></div>
<div id="stadium1" class="team activeteam eleven"><div>
```

Now what i want to do is find the first "activeteam" class and then target the previous div to that, in this scenario that would be stadiumSeats1

I tried using

```
$('.activeteam').prev('div');
$('.activeteam')[0].prev('div');
```

fwiw i am using [hopscotch tour](http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/) and my aim is to target that specific div.

I can access the stadium1 div fine with

```
$('.activeteam')[0];
```

But its the div before it i need. Theres lots of examples out there for 
    $('#activeteam').prev('div');

But this is a bit different because im trying to access a particular element of a class so not sure how to structure it.

Comment: `.prev` will only look at the exact previous sibling. Are you sure that is the element you are trying to find?

Comment: do you mean it will only look within the stadium1 div? Basically whats going on is one of a possible 9 entries will be active and only 1. This will be the class with activeteam. But the div is not what i want to click on, its always the div previous to activeclass div as each div loads a different popup and when you click the div you proceed to the next step but if i click on stadium1 it will load the wrong popup so i need to target the div directly before/above the activeteam div

Comment: Before and above are two very different things. The structure you show is perhaps not the structure you are actually using. Can you verify that the structure is accurate?

Comment: Try `$('div').get($('div').index($('.activeteam'))-1)`

Comment: sorry for not being clear. stadiumSeats1 is before the stadium1 div. I believe its also above it too. But yes its always this way, there would be up to 9 groups of these divs and im always targetting the div directly before stadium1. There would never be another div between them. I do apologize im not explaining it clearly

Comment: and just to clarify further its always activeteam[0] im targetting, there is only ever one active at anytime

Comment: $('.activeteam:first').prev('div');

Comment: the above also worked but wasnt a solution so i couldnt choose it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$($('div').get($('div').index($('.activeteam'))-1))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3g8afjhu/